# Rails form validation does not work if form is initially hidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, hidden

I am having a weird issue with rails form validation. Currently the validation works fine if the form is visible when the page loads but nothing happens if the form is initially hidden and displayed upon user interaction with the page.

Model

```
class PushNotification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :application, foreign_key: :appId, primary_key: :appid

  validates :message, :presence => true, :length => { maximum: 75 }
  validates :max_message_frequency, :presence => true, :numericality => {:only_integer => true, :greater_than => 0}
  validates :appId, :presence => true
end
```

Html Form

```
<div id="push-message-tab" class="tab-section">
    <%= form_for(PushNotification.new,
                     url: messaging_messaging_cohort_create_push_path(@application, @cohort),
                     remote: true, validate: true,
                     html: {
                             id: :push_notification_create_form,
                             class: 'new_push_notification_create ' + (@cohort.new_record? ? 'default-segment' : ''),
                             autocomplete: "off"
                     }) do |f| %>


            <div class="push-form-component-header">
              <%= f.label :message, 'Message' %>
              <span id="message-char-counter-wrapper"><b id="char-counter">75</b> characters left</span>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
              <%= f.submit "Save", id:'submit-push', class: 'with-spinner', data: {waiting_text: "Saving"} %>
            </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

If push-message-tab element is visible when the page loads the rails form validation works great but it doesn't when I specify style="display: none" and toggle the visibility option on the fly. The form will be sent without performing any sort of validation.

I am using rails 3.1 with ruby 1.9.2

Thank you for your support

Comment: Do you mean client side validation or server side validation? If server side, it's impossible the data not been validated as long as form submitted correctly.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using client side validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using the **client_side_validations** gem.

Based on their documentation (https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations) and assuming you are talking about client-side validations I would recommend trying something like this in your javascript:

```
$('#your_form').resetClientSideValidations();
```

Just after you set the form as being displayed.

Comment: It works only *after* the form has been made visible. If it is called when the form is still hidden it doesn't work.

Comment: That's what I said "Just after you set the form as being displayed."