# Client Side Validation Gem Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-side-validation

I'm using client side validations gem for a form on a coming soon page and no matter what I've done I can't get the form to show the validations.

Here is the form

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <p><%= msg %></p>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Username" %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
  <button class="btnSmall" type="submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create User"><img  src="/assets/arrowWhite.png" alt="Submit Credentials" /></button>

  <button class="btnLarge" type="submit" name="submit">Submit<img class="arrowWhite1x" src="/assets/arrowMobileWhite.png" alt="Submit Credentials" /><img class="arrowWhite2x" src="/assets/arrowMobileWhite@2x.png" /><</button>

<% end %>
```

I'm loading sending the form via AJAX and so I'm also loading the validations via JS like this

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#new_user').enableClientSideValidations()
```

This is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :username

  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
  validates :email, :email_format => true
end
```

Comment: Do you have this line `//= require rails.validations` in your `app\assets\javascripts\application.js` file?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem: no errors in the JS console, it simply did not work - no validation, no message, nothing. I could get it to work temporarily if I called `$('form').enableClientSideValidations()` or `$('form[data-validate]').validate();` manually from the JS console.

It turned out that the [ClientSideValidation gem does not work if the form is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448308/rails-form-validation-does-not-work-if-form-is-initially-hidden). The functions `resetClientSideValidations()` or `enableClientSideValidations()` have to be called *after* the form has been made visible. If they are called before, when the form is still hidden, they have no effect.

```
$('form').enableClientSideValidations();  # works only if form visible
```

Other reasons why the gem would not work are version conflicts, have you tried to update the gems, to run the generators with `rails g client_side_validations:copy_assets`, and to add the javascript references to your application.js?

If it is a dynamic form, one could try

```
$('form[data-validate]').validate();
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750174/client-side-validations-3-1-0-not-working-when-new-form-is-added-to-the-dom)